# Automatically Retrieve an Object URL link in S3 Public Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3

I am currently using AWS S3 Buckets (public) to store some video files. I would like to create an excel spreadsheet where it shows the file name in one column and the link to the S3 object in another column.

I've looked into using the CLI to pull each file's name and link, however, I can't seem to find any past research for public buckets.

Would anyone know how to use either the CLI or web console to print out an inventory list of the file name and url links in each public bucket?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain a file listing, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query Contents[].[Key] --output text
```

This will list the Key (filename) including the full path. (I put `[Key]` in brackets to force each name onto a new line.)

To add a column with the URL, simply construct a formula that inserts the Key into the URL. A URL will look like:

```
https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/foo.txt
```

Please note that the **Region name** is included in the URL, so change it to match the region of your bucket.

So, if Column A contained the Key, then you could make a URL with:

```
="https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/"&A1
```

Comment: Hi John, quick follow-up question. If I were to want to list objects within a specific file, how would I adjust the code to do so? Thanks!

Comment: @NateWalker Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question. Please also include what you mean by "list objects within a specific file".

Comment: Done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699363/extract-links-within-specific-folder-in-aws-s3-buckets    Thank you!