# Extract Links Within Specific Folder in AWS S3 Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line

I am trying to get my AWS S3 API to list objects that I have stored in my S3 buckets. I have successfully used the code below to pull some of the links from my S3 buckets.

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query Contents[].[Key] --output text
```

The problem is the output in my command prompt is not listing the entire S3 Bucket inventory list. Is it possible to alter this code so that the output on my CLI lists the full inventory? If not, is there a way to alter the code to target specific file names within the S3 Bucket? For example, all the file names in my bucket are dates, so I would try and pull all the links from the file titled 3_15_20 Videos within the "my-bucket" bucket. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many objects do you have? By default the command shows only 1000 in one run.

Comment: I have less than 1000, but the command prompt seems to pull different aspects of each object thus pushing the total number over 1000

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to pull different aspects of each object"? Could you please edit your object to show this output? If you use `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket`, are all objects listed?

Comment: My apologies, John. I realized there were some unnecessary JSON files in those buckets that I did not know were there in the first place (the buckets store video files). I have deleted the unnecessary files, but when I run the ```list-objects``` I am only getting a list of 292 objects. I ran the ```ls``` command like you said, and all necessary files were listed. Any idea why my inventory number is so low using this API command? Should I try an updated version of list-objects? Thanks again –

Answer (score 0):

From [list-objects — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html):

> `list-objects` is a paginated operation. Multiple API calls may be issued in order to retrieve the entire data set of results. You can disable pagination by providing the `--no-paginate` argument.

Therefore, try using `--no-paginate` and see whether it returns all objects.

If you are regularly listing a bucket that contains a huge number of objects, you could also consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file listing the contents of a bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the response, John! Where in the line of code would you put ```--no-paginate```? I have tried it at the end after ```--output text``` and immediately after ```list-objects``` but I keep pulling the same information. Thoughts? Thanks again!